# trouble reading excel file c #

Tags: c#, excel, frameworks, .net-3.5, excel-2007

Good morning guys.
I have many of excel files .
It is very strange but I can not read it. If I copy the contents in a new excel spreadsheet it all works perfectly.
I would like to avoid doing all conversions before reading. I tried all in all conventional ways of 'Extended Properties but I always make the same mistake: "External table is not in the expected format." Probably the files were created in Excel 97. But with the proper external method does not work.
Can you give me support? Thank you and good day

Here I try with the Extended Properties Excel 8.0, but I've tried them all.

```
string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + PercorsoCompletoFileExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
```

here I pass a select to take only certain columns. I repeat all works right if I copy the files to a new excel sheet but I wish it worked with that file original

```
strSQL = "SELECT [NumeroContratto] AS [Numero contratto],[Codice Cliente] as [Codice cliente],[Importo Tessera] as [Importo Tessera],[Costo contratto] as [Costo contratto],Spese,Commissioni,[Importo Servizi] as [Servizi],[Importo Sconto] as [Sconto],[Importo Addebito Totale] as [Totale]  from [" + foglio + "] where [Importo Addebito Totale] is not null";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Codes below work in my case.

By my experience, you need to save uploaded file in application directory first. If not will throw error when reading (.xlsx) file.

Use different connection string for (.xls) and (.xlsx) files.

```
string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
//This setting get from configuration file 
string FolderPath =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UploadFolder").ToString();
string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + "\\" + FileName);
//Save file  
FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
string conStr = "";
switch (Extension)
{
   case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
                break;
   case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\";";

                break;
        }
       conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath);
```

Setting in configuration file ("Web.config" in my case as it is web application)

```
<appSettings>
<add key="UploadFolder" value="UploadedFilesFolder" />
</appSettings>
```